# When I use the appCompatAcivity my app doesnt work on Android 6 and below

Tags: android, android-studio

When my app uses the `appCompatActivity` it doesn't work on Android 6 and below. But when I extend the `Activity` class it works. Is there anything I'm doing wrong. I have tried this with the default empty activity of android studio and its still the same error message of "APP NOT INSTALLED". I'm new to android development, so please take it easy on the comments. Thanks

Comment: How are you installing the app?

Comment: Your app might not be compatible with the installed version. Make sure the previous version is uninstalled before installing the new one.

Comment: Provide the exact error shown if the above doesn't work?

Comment: Was the previously installed app uninstalled?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing. Are you installing using commands or APK file?
What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please share a screenshot.

Comment: StackOverflow will not delete any posts if it is useful. Edit your question to make it clear. Your questions are not clear. What do you mean by build directly?

Comment: Take few minutes and try to frame a clear question.

Comment: Okay, I open Android Studio, and I create a new Project, I set the minimum SDK to Android 4.03. And I launch an empty activity Template, The main class by Default extends AppComapatActivity. I do not modify anything, I build the apk using the release variant. I send that APK to a phone running on Android 5.0. When I try installing I receive an error, "App not Installed". But when I extend the activity class, and rebuild, it works.

Comment: @Abhimanyu   please

Comment: Connect your mobile device using USB cable and try to run. For beginners that helps a lot.
You would be able to see the exact error by doing so.